# Context free grammar $\{a^n b^m c^k\; : \;k>m \; \; k>n\}$

Tags: context-free, automata, pushdown-automata, context-sensitive

Is this a CFL?
$$\{a^n b^m c^k\; : \;k>m \; \; k>n\}$$

When on seeing $a$'s and $b$'s I push them onto stack and as I see $ c$ as input if $ TOS$ is $b$ ,I pop them ,again if $TOS$ is a,I pop them so when my 
$TOS$ of stack is empty and input is$ c $,I do not make any changes in the stack and that clearly implies that i have no of $c$'s to be greater than both $a$ and $b$.

But its supoosedly not a CFL. Need help where I'm going wrong in constructing the PDA. Because supposedly a PDA can be made for this which makes it a CFL.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really sure your PDA recognizes that language. You state that the "number of c's to be greater than both a and b", but it is supposed to be no greater than each, separately, not together. Maybe you could try the pumping lemma on this language.